# Futurebuilder / Firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting the error in type cast:

> type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

I think it is caused by the line:
`final data = snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;`.

If I change the line `title: Text(data?["name"]),` to `Text(routeData['id']),` then I do see the correct id number so I think the problem is something to do with the firebase query / how I'm handling the result.

This is the full code (class ItemList lists the names of the records, then clicking on one of them takes the user to class ItemDetails which should display the details of the clicked on record):

```
void main() async {
   WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
   await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);

  runApp(Home());
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {

  // const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),

      routes: {
        '/': (context) => ItemList(),
        '/factfile': (context) => ItemDetails(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class ItemList extends StatelessWidget {
  ItemList({Key? key}) : super(key: key) {
    _stream = _reference.snapshots();
  }

  CollectionReference _reference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('table_name');

  late Stream<QuerySnapshot> _stream;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Item List'),
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: _stream,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          //Check error
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(child: Text('Some error occurred ${snapshot.error}'));
          }

          //Check if data arrived
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            //get the data
            QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = snapshot.data;
            List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> documents = querySnapshot.docs;

            //Convert the documents to Maps
            List<Map> items = documents.map((e) =>
            {
              'name': e['name'],
              'dlastupd': e['dlastupd'],
              'dlastupd date': DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(e['dlastupd'] * 1000),
              'id': e['id'],
            }).toList();

            // sort in descending date order
            items.sort((a, b) => b["dlastupd"].compareTo(a["dlastupd"]));

            //Display the list
            return ListView.builder(

                itemCount: items.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  //Get the item at this index
                  Map thisItem = items[index];
                  //Return the widget for the list items
                  return ListTile(

                    title: Text(formatDate(thisItem['dlastupd date'], [dd, '', M]) + " - " + thisItem['name']),
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.pushNamed(
                        context,
                        '/factfile',
                        arguments: {
                          'id': thisItem['id'],
                        },
                      );
                    },
                  );
                });
          }

          //Show loader
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        },
      ), //Display a list // Add a FutureBuilder
    );
  }
}

class ItemDetails extends StatelessWidget {

  Map routeData = {};

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    routeData = ModalRoute
        .of(context)
        ?.settings
        .arguments as Map;
    print(routeData);

    final DocumentReference docRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("table_name").doc(routeData['id']);


    return FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      future: docRef.get(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {

          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text("Waiting for future..."),
            ),
            body: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
          );
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text("Error"),
            ),
            body: Center(child: Text("Error: ${snapshot.error}")),
          );
        } else {

          final data = snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;

          return Scaffold(    
              appBar: AppBar(
                title: Text(data?["name"]),
              ),
              body: Center(child: Text("Data has been loaded")),    
          );    
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you get when your `print(snapshot.data!.data())` right before the line that raises the error?

Comment: Hi Frank it is returning null

Comment: So that makes it seen like the document exists, but doesn't contain any data.

Comment: Thank you @FrankvanPuffelen. I've just run it again, it hangs for many minutes (there is a circular progress indictor so I think it's in the ConnectionState.waiting part of the if statement). Then it fails and it prints the "null" message in console. I've checked the id number in the firebase database and there is a record. I'm wondering if the problem is that although there isn't much data there are about 350 fields in the table? Could that be causing a malfunction?